# Ejecutar query Mongo en Java directamente (a pelo)

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8

Tengo un problema debido a que desde mi aplicación java leo un fichero en formato JSON y en este fichero me viene una query de Mongo la cual tendría que ejecutar tal cual está pero viendo las opciones que tengo, lo que he visto es que tendría que utilizar BasicDBObject o Document para poder ejecutarla, por lo que tendría que reconvertir mi query para poder ejecutarla. La query en cuestión sería algo tal que así:

```
[
     {
        "$match":{
           "organization":{
              "$in":[
                 "organization1"
              ]
           },
           "_id.miId":"device.id"
        }
     },
     {
        "$group":{
           "_id":{
              "value":"$first.value",
              "channelId":"$channel"
           },
           "count":{
              "$sum":1
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "$group":{
           "_id":{
              "channelId":"$_id.channelId"
           },
           "accum":{
              "$addToSet":{
                 "name":"$_id.value",
                 "count":"$count"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ]
```

}
}

¿No sería posible alguna forma de poder ejecutar mi query directamente? Y en caso de no ser posible, ¿hay algún método ya implementado que pasándole la query lo pase a un formato que pueda ejecutar?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Eso es una query o el resultado de una query? Son dos cosas distintas... eso para Java no es otra cosa que un JSON, y puedes leerlo como tal si quieres. Pero es que te pregunta no se entiende, creo que deberías replantearla, usando bien los conceptos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Eso es una query agregada, la cual como bien dices puedo leerla desde java como tal puesto que es un JSON (eso ya lo estoy haciendo), la duda es que para ejecutarla (por lo que he visto hasta ahora), tendría que parsearla lo cual me parece muy tedioso teniendo la consulta completa... No sé si habría alguna opción mejor.

Comment: No entiendo realmente tu duda: *la duda es que para ejecutarla (por lo que he visto hasta ahora), tendría que parsearla lo cual me parece muy tedioso teniendo la consulta completa...*  ¿?  ¿Podrías explicarte mejor? ¿A qué te refieres con *query agregada*? Eso sigue siendo un JSON, no veo lo que sea una *query agregada*  ¿? Sigo pensando que eso es el resultado de una consulta y lo que tendrías que hacer en ese caso es pasar la consulta que produce ese resultado, capturar el resultado y leerlo como un JSON.  ¿No es eso lo que quieres? Si no es eso, explica lo que quieres, porque no se entiende